# "No route to host": understanding networking between Vagrant VMs

Tags: virtualbox, centos, vagrant

I'd like to have a pair of VMs with a network between them.  I made the following Vagrantfile

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.define :alpha do |alpha|
    alpha.vm.box = "centos-6.4"
    alpha.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.50.2"

    alpha.vm.provision "shell", inline: "yum install -y nc"
  end

  config.vm.define :beta do |beta|
    beta.vm.box = "centos-6.4"
    beta.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.50.10"
    beta.vm.provision "shell", inline: "yum install -y nc"
  end
end
```

At first, I thought that things were working, because I can do

> vagrant ssh alpha

and then

> ping 192.168.50.10

or

> ssh 192.168.50.10

And those both work.  But it looks like it's actually *only* those two operations that work. If I have beta listen on port 3000 and try to connect to it, I can't:

```
$ ssh -p3000 192.168.50.10
ssh: connect to host 192.168.50.10 port 3000: No route to host
```

How can I get it so that *all* traffic can pass between the two VMs?

I've got VirtualBox 4.2.18 as the provider and Vagrant 1.3.3

**Edit:** After more experimentation, I can reproduce this with CentOS on VirtualBox alone, and if I change the base-box to an Ubuntu one, I do *not* have this problem (with no other changes to the Vagrantfile). Is this a problem with networking with CentOS on VirtualBox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out this was just the iptables on the base box tripping me up. Switching this off (`service iptables stop` to temporarily disable the firewall) allowed me to route between the two machines.

Comment: For newer versions try systemctl stop firewalld.service

Comment: I run into this every time in this exact situation, and every time it surprises and frustrates me.